# How to determine names of running services in Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos7

Having to manage a few production servers over different Linux distributions, I find it hard to remember the exact name of the service to restart/stop.
Is there anyway systematic way to determine the name of a running service, and subsequently being able to run

```
service <service name> status/stop/reload/start
```

commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, programs that execute tasks in the background are normally known as “services” and “daemons”.

We can use "service" or "systemctl" to manage these servcies.
Example: 
-service service-name start
-systemctl start service-name

Mostly custom service files will be at "/etc/init.d/" directory and custom systemd files will be at "/etc/systemd/system/" directory

Comment: thank you, i managed to find it using systemctl and list out all running services.

Answer (score 0):

for centos 7 use

```
systemctl list-unit-files
```